# Import equation from text file in R function

Tags: r, equation, txt

I am trying to load an equation from .txt file into an R function. The equations are very long but for sake of simplicity my test.txt file contains only  a + b.

```
equation <- function(a,b) {
data <- read.delim("test.txt", header = F, col.names="equation", strip.white=F)
return (data$equation) 
}

equation(1,1)
```

I have tried the code above which should give the result of 2 (1+1) but the data is loaded as factor and I cannot crack how to parse it as attributes.

Comment: What do you mean by “parse it as attributes”? As far as I can tell your code works, although the entire function could be replaced by just `readLines('test.txt')`.

Comment: At the moment it returns  "[1] a + b" instead of numeric answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `readLines`.

```
eq <- function(a, b) eval(parse(text=readLines("equ.txt")))
eq(1, 1)
# [1] 2
```

Comment: This has worked! Thank you kind stranger.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval(parse())`:

```
equation <- function(a,b) {
    data <- readr::read_file("test.txt")
    return( eval(parse(text = data) ))
}
equation(4,5)
[1] 9
```

Comment: This returned "Error in parse(text = data) : <text>:1:6: unexpected input
1: a + b"